# Flutter Firebase - Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRAnalytics'

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-analytics

I am working on a flutter project on my M3 Macbook and trying to implement FirebaseAnalytics (not first time btw). I followed th guide completely and I got the error;

[image: build error]

I tried to clean cache of `pub`, `xcode` and `simulator`. Also upgraded my flutter version from `3.16.9` to `3.19.0`. Also tried every single solution request from `StackOverflow` and `Github` but no luck. here is my firebase package dependencies;

pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.2.6 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  firebase_analytics: ^10.8.6
  firebase_core: ^2.22.0
  firebase_messaging: ^14.7.15
```

doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.0, on macOS 14.3.1 23D60 darwin-arm64, locale
    tr-TR)
    • Flutter version 3.19.0 on channel stable at /Users/taha/Dev/core/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision bae5e49bc2 (6 days ago), 2024-02-13 17:46:18 -0800
    • Engine revision 04817c99c9
    • Dart version 3.3.0
    • DevTools version 2.31.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/taha/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15C500b
    • CocoaPods version 1.15.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.86.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.82.0
```

XCode Version: 15.2 (15C500b)

MacOS Version: 14.3.1 (23D60)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying multiple ways (updating os, cleaning the cache, importing package manually etc.) to overcome this issue realized that cocoapods has a new version. I was using `1.15.1`. After updating cocoapods with following command:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Cleared the cache with

```
pod cache clean --all
```

Removed following files and folders under `ios`

```
.symlinks
Pods
Podfile.lock
```

and then I installed all pods under project with

```
pod install
```

After all it built normally.

I hope it will be useful